# How to write the status got from a command as a .txt BATCH

Tags: batch-file

A Whole New Edit:
I have managed to get a log from a cmd , then generate a file using the log called status (no extension) , then I call a batch called status.bat , and here's the code:

```
Find /N "License:" "status" >> license.txt
```

this was good for me , except for the fact that it shows the line number , and the word -------Status above it , is there anyway to make it not show the line number and the "---------Status" above each one?
thanks!

Comment: show us the code you have tried, and tell use what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the status.bat into:

```
type status | find "License:" >> license.txt
```

This will not show the ---status or line numbers.  However, it will be slower, but that **might** only matter if the file is several megs in size.

See `type /?` and `find /?` for help.